# Regex match png thumbnails

Tags: regex, image, png

How can I perform with regex that all png's are selected?
The URL to the png is as follows:

```
http://www.sudomemo.net/images/dynamic/thumbframe/D4C601_0DEE3B3BAF08F_016.png
```

I am loading the entire HTML page, but I only want these links with the png's.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: In this format http://www.sudomemo.net/images/dynamic/thumbframe/XXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX_XXX.png

Comment: Which language are you using? And please provide more examples and code you have tried

Comment: I'm using B4A and Regex. I have edited the post. I don't know from where to start, this is why I dont have any code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more specific regex would be like

```
http:\/\/www.sudomemo.net\/images\/dynamic\/thumbframe\/[^.]+\.png
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/tE0dL9/5

Answer (score 1):

I try this take if you want

```
http:\/\/(.*?)\.png$
```

**SEE DEMO :** http://regex101.com/r/jB7yO7/1

Comment: Your regex highlights other png's as well, I only wanted these who begin with `http://www.sudomemo.net/images/dynamic/thumbframe/` But I have already found an answer. Thanks as well ;)